# Como controlar setValidators em angular?

Tags: angularjs, angular

Eu usando formulários relativos no angular 4, estou com problema ao controlar o setValidators em estrutura um pouco grande, como abaixo:

```
this.criteria = this.formBuilder.group({
      discount: this.formBuilder.group({
        percentage: [null],
        amount: [null],
      }),
    });
```

Essa é a forma que estou fazendo para controlar. Porém, quando há mais de dois "nos" o controle não funciona, dando o seguinte erro: Property 'control' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.ts(2339)

```
this.criteria.controls['discount.percentage'].setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

Answer (score 1):

tudo bem?

Para cara control você deve usar o método `.get()`. Por exemplo:

```js
this.criteria.get('discount').get('percentage').setValidators([Validators.required]);
```

Uma outra forma de resolver seu problema seria especificar os Validators na definição do seu formulário.

```js
this.criteria = this.formBuilder.group({
    discount: this.formBuilder.group({
    percentage: [null, Validators.required],
    amount: [null],
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

não use controls.
use assim:

```
this.criteria.get('discount').get('percentage').setValidators([Validators.required]);
```